# Iomega StorCenter opinions

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage

I saw iomega storcenter with 12 HDDs with very favorable price. Experts, what do you think about that :) Vmware certified! :) This is not a question, but I would be glad if you provide some pros/cons. Thanks!

Comment: I think products are usually cheap for good reasons. You get what you pay for.

Comment: Well it's a NAS not a SAN, so what's your intended use for it? Are you going to use it with VMware?

Comment: Welcome to SF! Please see the FAQ and feel free to post away with specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

We generally don't do purchasing questions on here - what I can tell you is that the particular part you're looking at is a very generic basic NAS box, certainly it will present itself as iSCSI or NFS over it's 4 GigE NICs allowing it to store vmdks on it - without knowing your actual requirements it would be hard to give an actual opinion one way or another.

Comment: Have to agree here We need to know what you need it for before we can recommend it.

Comment: recommend NFS... getting iSCSI to round robin balance with this thing might be painful.

Comment: agree with SmS - plus iSCSI is just horrid